# Moving Rectangle in Quartz

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, quartz-2d

I am attempting to learn the basics of quartz and do not understand why this will not work
 - this should move the red rectangle to the right when the button is pushed, bat at the momoent, it does not do anything
 - the "NSLog(A"help"); was to try to figure out if the button was functioning 
 - thanks

```
@implementation QuartzView

-(IBAction)moveRight:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Help");

    lR += 50;

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext // 1
                               currentContext] graphicsPort];

    // Drawing code here.
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);// 3
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (lR, 0, 200, 100 ));

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shoot, i meant the last line to say "CGRectMake (lR, 0 , 200, 100));

Comment: Fixed it for you. You can edit your post, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to call setNeedsDisplay in drawRect; that simply says, "now that I've drawn the view, make me do it again!"

You want to call setNeedsDisplay in your action, to update the screen after you moves the rectangle.

Comment: Ok i tried that but that still doesnt work, it seems that despite the '[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];' the display does not reset.... is there any trick that I dont know about to get the rectangle to redraw?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self setNeedsDisplay]` inside moveRight after you increment lR.

Comment: NSView setNeedsDisplay: does take an argument.